# WildFly App Dev: how to reflect the runtime classpath at development time?

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, java-ee-7

I am working on a Project that is deployed as .war WebApp on a single WildFly 16 instance.

Using IntelliJ Idea UE with Maven as development environment, I ask myself how to reflect the classpath that the deployed app will see at runtime in the development classpath at development time.

I have read about [implicit dependencies](https://docs.wildfly.org/16/Developer_Guide.html#which-are-the-implicit-module-dependencies) in the Developer Guide. 
So I conclude that the classpath of my deployment will contain the elements from the "Dependencies that are always added" column plus those that are added on trigger conditions (in my case these are Weld, Web, Hibernate, Resteasy, EJB3).

How can I figure out what Maven artifacts I have to import so that my development classpath equals the runtime classpath of my WebApp?

I would like to solve dependency conflicts at development time, not at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [WildFly 16 Bill of Materials (BOM)](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.wildfly.bom/wildfly-javaee8/16.0.0.Final/pom) for that. I'm sure you are well aware of *Maven's* import feature for artifacts of type *POM*. Just in case you are not, add these lines to your *Maven* `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-javaee8</artifactId>
        <version>16.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

It enables you to reference most of WildFly's artifacts (or at least the relevant ones) as well as the Java EE 8 specification artifacts. Here's an example:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<!-- And so on... -->
```

You still need to list all the dependencies you require though. If you have additional dependencies (not provided by WildFly), you should package them in your *WAR* or *EAR*. This way you shouldn't get any conflicts.

Oh, and one more thing, because you mentioned several dependencies, which are WildFly specific (e.g. Weld and Hibernate): Try sticking to Java EE APIs, where possible. It enables you to port your application to other application servers faster, if needed.

Comment: Thank you for answer. If I look into the BOM, there is no mention of jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec, for example. How would I know that this exact artifact is provided?

Comment: Oh I see, I would find it to be listed here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wildfly.bom/wildfly-javaee8/16.0.0.Final

Comment: @Thomas, yes, that's right and I totally forgot to mention it. Sorry about that. So to sum up: BOMs too can import BOMs. You will need to dig into those BOM `pom.xml` files to find all the _Maven_ coordinates you need.

Comment: OK, but if I update the WildFly version, I will have to do all of this again, right? There is no simple solution to resolve classpath conflicts, as I can see.

Comment: @Thomas, no, you won't have to do all of it again. Some of the coordinates stay the same, such es Hibernate, Weld, and so on - unless they get dropped of course. The Java EE specification artifact coordinates will change, because the specification version is reflected in the _artifactId_.